# Unable to fetch item using getitem method

Tags: security, sitecore-api

I was trying to access item using getitem method from SOAP service.

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.context.Database.GetItem(<ID>)
```

But Item is null. I tried to fetch using Id and path also. And checked the connection strings as well. Does the SOAP service need to have any special permissions to fetch the item? Do I have to check any other things why SOAP service is not able to search.

Answer (score 1):

My guess here would be that the SOAP service execution doesn't trigger Sitecore's http request pipeline which are responsible to resolve the information which are normally available through the `Sitecore.Context` static class - nor does this normally what the developers should use to expose an API endpoint in Sitecore web application.

Instead of SOAP service, you should look in the following options if you're not tied to SOAP service approach:

- [Use Web API controller](https://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/)
- [Use Sitecore Services Client](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice)

Comment: ok....I will check on this....I am working on Sitecore 7.2 version. Hope it supports.